# How to render nested arrays in objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object like this:

```
 myObject: {
  "artists" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "id" : "423587fgerhk34t",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://url",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 320,
        "url" : "https://url",
        "width" : 320
      }],
      "name" : "Artist Name",
    } ] 
   }
  }
```

Excuse me for sounding stupid, but how do I, in my React app, reach the ID, images and name?
Can someone ELI5 this for me?

I've tried

```
Object.entries(myObject).map()

Object.keys(myObject).map()

myObject.artists.items.map()
```

but none of them works, at least not what I'm trying.

(I cannot change the object, it's a response from an API)

Really appreciate some help here. I need to render images and artistname and save the ID.

Edit, been trying this for example:

```
  const displaySearchResult = Object.keys(myObject).map((artist) =>
    <div className="search-result-item">
      <img src={artist.images[1].url} alt="Artist"/>
      <b key={artist.id}>{artist.name}</b>
    </div>
    )
```

But basically, all I'm getting is

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {href, items, limit, next, offset, previous, total}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." (Objects.entries)

or

"Cannot read properties of undefined ('reading items')" (myObject.artists.items.map())

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Are you able to provide a code sample of what you're trying to map too? i.e this object being used in situ of the rendering component.

Comment: Does your object really have a top-level property called myObject?  If you named the variable myObject too, then you'll have `myObject.myObject.artists.items.map(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Your third attempt looks right to me, we need more info to determine what mistake you're making - try a [mcve]

Comment: @James well it's not named that from the API, but I've put it in a state called myObject, if that makes sense... (let [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({}))

Comment: Your edit has now introduced some code with `searchResults` as the thing being mapped. That differs entirely from the rest of the question.

Comment: @Jamiec I'm trying to make my code anonymous here which is why I'm changing everything to generic names. I obviously forgot to do that in my update.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given the only mistake you seem to be making is iterating over the keys of `myObject` - which only has 1 key `artists` and that clearly does not give what you're trying to do judging by the HTML you're trying to output.

In actual fact you need to use `map` over `myObject.artists.items` which is an array of objects with properties which seem to match what you're trying to output:

```
const displaySearchResult = myObject.artists.items.map((artist) =>
      ... rest of your code
);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but my applications fails with message: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items').

Comment: @Ned if right before this line you add `console.log(myObject.artists)` what do you see in the console?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 2 multiple image URL's dynamically for a single name, you can try with the below code.

```
const displaySearchResult = myObject.artists.items.map((artist) =>
    <div className="search-result-item">
      {artist.images.map((img) =>
      <img src={img.url} alt="Artist"/>
      )}
      <b key={artist.id}>{artist.name}</b>
    </div>
    )
```

Or
If you want to display one image with name and another image with same name dynamically, then you can try below code.

```
const displaySearchResult = myObject.artists.items.map((artist) =>
    <div className="search-result-item">
      {artist.images.map((img) =>
      <div>
        <img src={img.url} alt="Artist"/>
        <b key={artist.id}>{artist.name}</b>
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
    )
```